# Is there a better way to read cmdline file inside each process directory in /proc

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

So in my current project i have to get all the running processes on a linux system, so what i have done is use the dirent header file to get all the relevant directories (the ones beginning with integers).

So my question is, have you any thoughts of a better method of reading the cmdline file of each directory, other than just looping over each PID and reading the file in and comparing it with my comparison string, because this seems like it'll increase memory consumption and needlessly slow the program down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> …other than just looping over each PID and reading the file in and comparing it with my comparison string…

That's exactly what you should do.

Reading in files from `/proc` is fast -- `/proc` nodes are not files; reading them does not involve disk access -- and should not increase your process's memory consumption so long as you free any buffers properly.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted some confirmation that it wouldn't slow anything down needlessly.